# Using an oil filter o-ring in place of an oil cooler o-ring?

Tags: oil-seal

Buying a new oil cooler o-ring for my 98 Mazda 626 2L where I live is extremely expensive, I'm not sure that even the dealer ship has the right part and I can't seem to find a part number anywhere.  I ran across this post regarding [changing the oil cooler gasket on a Mazda MX-6](http://www.mx6.com/forums/2404812-post4.html) which uses a similar o-ring type gasket:

> But yes, using the gasket off a regular oil filter does seem to work fine.

Anyone ever heard of such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the O-rings in both applications are designed to be compatible with oil, material suitability shouldn't be a concern. As long as the O-rings share the same size and profile, the two should be interchangeable.